# How to determine who is beeping on my computer?

Tags: operating-systems, tracing

I have HP dm3 laptop and windows 7 installed on it. There is some beep for a 0.5 seconds periodically. There is no regularity. I did not found nothing suspicious in evets log. There is nothing suspicious in processes running on a machine. There is also avg 2012 anitvirus installed. My question is, how can I trace who is sending that signal. Which software do I need for this purpose or which functions to use in c/c++/c# to write a program by myself. I know for sure that this sound comes from sound card and not from pc-speaker.

Comment: Try going to command prompt and pressing Ctrl-G and enter. Does that make the same sound?

Comment: Then go to **control pannel** **sound** in the **Sounds** tab, and select the **"no sounds"** sound scheme (temporarily), to determine if it is standard notification sounds or not.  if it is , then you could discover which one it is, that could provide clues as to what is occuring.

Comment: 1. I have already checked before and this is not pc speaker sound! 2. And all the system sounds are disabled for all events.

Comment: Then we need a better definition , of what the sound is comming from. because **I know for sure that this sound comes from sound card and not from pc-speaker** & **this is not pc speaker sound**  just is not defining it.  The little Piezio beeper or tiny speaker on the motherboard , is A "pc speaker" (see the problem?)  The use of the word "BEEP" can sort of  define the "Beep" driver in a windows system, or the bios beeper.  Although we can understand you get a Beep of some sort, which could be from a Keyboard buffer overflow for one thing.

Comment: I know this is old.. but what about if you mute the sound?  (then you'll see if it's some component making the sound). You could open the laptop and use your ear particularly if you can time when the sound happens

Answer (score 1):

Try opening mixer (click speaker icon on the tray, and then mixer).

The window will expand to show a volume bar per each application using audio.

When the beep comes, you should be able to identify which application it is as its volume bar will go blueish for a period of beep.

note: if the beep goes under category 'system sound' then it will require more investigation. But let us deal step by step with the issue.

Comment: Hmmm... I do that and one of the sliders is titled "Name not available".

Comment: After some tests I have found that this sound is not from sound card. So if it is not from soundcard so this is pc speaker. So how do I trace that sound? The system is working 100% correct, just that annoying beep...